# SQL, Select One row with min field value from subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have following SQL query:

```
 select count(t.id) from Tickets t 
    where t.IsPaid = 1 and t.Price_id = (select price.Id from Prices price 
            where price.Product_id = '7E67DAFB-C819-4715-830A-7C89EC986E4F' AND price.Quantity > (select count(t1.Id) from Tickets t1 
                where t1.IsPaid = 1 AND t1.Price_id IN (select pr.Id from Prices pr
                    where price.Product_id = pr.Id)))
```

---

The question is: how to get the row with min value of price.Price1 field from this part of my code?

```
(select price.Id from Prices price 
            where price.Product_id = '7E67DAFB-C819-4715-830A-7C89EC986E4F' AND price.Quantity > (select count(t1.Id) from Tickets t1 
                where t1.IsPaid = 1 AND t1.Price_id IN (select pr.Id from Prices pr
                    where price.Product_id = pr.Id)))
```

I expect that as a result of second part of my code would be only Id of the ONE row. Right now this code always returning me all prices.
Here is relationships in main tables [Database structure and relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jpAx.png)

---

I was trying different methods like this:

```
(select price.Id, MIN(Price1) from Prices price 
        where price.Product_id = '7E67DAFB-C819-4715-830A-7C89EC986E4F' AND price.Quantity > (select count(t1.Id) from Tickets t1 
            where t1.IsPaid = 1 AND t1.Price_id IN (select pr.Id from Prices pr
                where price.Product_id = pr.Id)) Group by Id)
```

But the result is: [Result with MIN function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDXTV.png)

Example of data in Prices table: [Prices table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEwf5.png)

---

Example of data in Tickets table: [Tickets table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1Npi.png)

Comment: I can't see `price.Price1` field in your query

Comment: please edit question to better explain exactly what you have - input data - actual sql - current output and required output

Comment: Because I was trying to provide there logic with MIN(Price1) function, which requires Group By statement in my case, but I always got response all Prices entity.

Comment: Please provide a table with small sample of data you are pulling from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you are trying to achieve:
for a given product id find the lowest possible price that has available unpaid tickets and then show how many tickets are available

If that's correct:

```
SELECT isnull(ticket_count, 0) AS ticket_count
FROM
(
        SELECT * 
        FROM (SELECT Price_Id, MIN(Price1) OVER (Partition By Product_id) min_price from Prices) x
        WHERE min_price=Price1
    ) p
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT COUNT(Id) ticket_count, Price_Id FROM Tickets WHERE IsPaid=1 GROUP BY Price_Id
    ) t ON p.Price_Id=t.Price_Id 
WHERE p.Quantity > t.ticket_count
```

Answer (score 0):

> The question is: how to get the row with min value of price.Price1
>   field from this part of my code?

Simple:

```
(select TOP 1 price.Id 
  from Prices price 
  where price.Product_id = '7E67DAFB-C819-4715-830A-7C89EC986E4F' 
  AND price.Quantity > (
    select count(t1.Id) 
    from Tickets t1 
    where t1.IsPaid = 1 
    AND t1.Price_id IN (select pr.Id from Prices pr where price.Product_id = pr.Id)
  )
ORDER BY price.Price1 ASC
)
```

Comment: Not so. This is subquery and due to this condition we can't use ORDER BY construction.

Comment: You **can** order the results when `TOP` is specified, as pointed by the error message you get when using `ORDER BY` in a subquery without it: *"The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, **unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.**"*

Comment: @Madnestranger yes, as Alberto pointed out, I'm afraid you're wrong.  You can use ORDER BY in a subquery if you also specify a TOP value.   This solution would work.